# Hide Radio button for custom payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

[image]
we are using custom payment module.  we want to keep that payment method enable .

but we don't want to show this payment under Checkout > payment method. so we deleted the design part of that module.

but the Radio button is still displaying under "payment method " at the last.

How to Hide that radio button only for that payment method?

Comment: what are the code for payment method. ?

Comment: is there any way to find the code ?

Comment: inspect element and you will find that code. it is after  `id="p_method_ {here is code} `

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want the payment method enabled but not available to the checkout proccess? What for?

Comment: Go admin side : System ->Configuration -> Payment Methods ( Your custom method If Enable Yes then cahnge to: NO and save)

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis for payment through mobile app.

Comment: @Abdul for some reason we need to enable the payment method

Comment: can you send custom payment extension name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add if condition on payment method code

```
 <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" <?php if($_code=='yourcode') { ?> style="display:none"<?php } ?> value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
```

Comment: i got  the payment method code, in which file , i have to add the above if condition?

Comment: Checkout/onepage/payment/method.phtml

Answer (score 1):

In

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
```

near line 44 you will find

```
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
         $_code = $_method->getCode();
         ?>
         <dt id="dt_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
```

Change it to

```
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
        if($_code == 'YOUR_CODE'){continue;}//add this line
        ?>
        <dt id="dt_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
```